# Receiving a `globalObj.setTimeout is not a function` error for basic jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, react-hooks-testing-library

I am attempting to test a basic Axios hook and am receiving:

```
TypeError: globalObj.setTimeout is not a function

      at setImmediatePolyfill (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/build/helpers/timers.js:59:20)
      at Object.then (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/build/flushMicroTasks.js:26:32)
```

As far as I can tell the expected's are passing but am still getting this error for some reason which is failing the test. This is react native with the following package.json below. The hook works on my app, I'm assuming it has something to do with the testing library but I'm not sure what.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.4",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^8.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "expo": "^43.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "jest-expo": "^43.0.1",
    "miragejs": "^0.1.42",
    "react-hooks-testing-library": "^0.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0",
    "yarn-upgrade-all": "^0.5.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My Axios hook:

```
// ./src/hooks.js

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useAPI = (apiFunction, params) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        apiFunction(params)
            .then(({data}) => {
                setData(data);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setError("Something went wrong!");
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }, [apiFunction, params]);

    return [isLoading, data, error];
};
```

My test:

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { act } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import axios from "axios";
import { useAPI } from "../../Hooks/useAPI";

jest.mock("axios");
const mockData = {data: [{"test":"test"}]};


const getTestData = () => axios.get("/testEndpoint");

describe("fetch api data", () => {
    describe("on success", () => {
        it("should set data to test data and set isLoading false", async () => {
            axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockData);
            const {result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useAPI(getTestData));

            await act( async () => {
                await waitForNextUpdate();
            })

            const {data: expectedData} = mockData;

            expect(result.current[0]).toEqual(false);
            expect(result.current[1]).toEqual(expectedData);
            expect(result.current[2]).toEqual(null);
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace? Just two lines?

Comment: It is indeed. Thats all the entire test spits out.

Comment: even with `jest --verbose`?

Comment: Yep, same result. I'm wondering if it could be something with my jest setup because `globalObj` refers to `window`.

Comment: probably something to file on the jest issue tracker, too.

Comment: Perhaps, I just changed the `globalObj` to use `global` instead of `window` and the test passed. Its set to default to it when `window` is unavailable in the timers.js file. Do you think this would be an issue with jest or with @testing-library/react-native?

Comment: I would probably be the wrong person to ask (I've been setting up a bunch of jest suites recently, but haven't run into this error). Probably see if you can turn this into a true [mcve], and if you can, you pretty much immediately know which project will want to know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my own issue. I had set `global.window = {}` in the jest.setup.js file earlier. @testing-library/react-native uses a timers.js file in which they refer to `globalObj` which they obtain from the following: `const globalObj = typeof window === 'undefined' ? global : window;`. As window was not technically undefined, globalObj was being set to `{}` and did not have access to global functionality.